# Why do bean validation Min/Max constraints not support the double type?

Tags: java, constraints, precision, bean-validation

Could somebody please explain to me why the JPA supports the `double` type as a field type, but the bean validation constaints in `javax.validation.constraints` (i.e. [@Min](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html)/[@Max](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/validation/constraints/Max.html)) do not support it?
I know documentation says this is due to rounding errors, but if I choose the field type to be `double` I already admit that I don't care that much about the explicit precision.

The scenario I ran into this dilemma is the following: I have an Entity that represents a point on the earth's surface. If the precision is within a few centimeters it's fine. It looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Point {

    /**
     * The longitude in radians.
     */
    @Min(-Math.Pi)
    @Max(Math.Pi)
    double longitude;
    /**
     * The latitude in radians.
     */
    @Min(-Math.Pi / 2)
    @Max(Math.Pi / 2)
    double latitude;

}
```

Unfortunately this does not work, because the annotations do not support the double type. But using `BigDecimal` instead is not really an option, because I have some extensive computation with multiple points going on that still needs to be reasonably fast. I worked around it by defining a custom constraint check that does work with `double`s, but somehow I think there is something I'm missing in the whole story. So, what am I missing?

Comment: Please note that JPA and Bean Validation are two entirely separate APIs. I fixed the title, some wording and tags accordingly. Brilliant question example btw. What Bean Validation implementation are you using? Hibernate Validator?

Comment: Yes, right now I'm using Hibernate Validator.

Comment: You actually can annotate a double with Min or Max (at least in Hibernate Validator). The double type is supported. Your problem seems to be that you cannot specify a double as constraint parameter. There the spec indeed enforces a long. Have you considered using DecimalMin and DecimalMax? You could specify your min and max values as strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because of rounding. But not because of the problem that a double is may not correct enough to express the number you want. It is more that the annotation value (of `Min` and `Max`) is of type long, so it can not express any number with decimal places. On the other hand you can not use a double to express exact all numbers that a long can express.

So the API designers had to decide for one of the two ways (long or double)

Comment: Thanks for that insight, I didn't look at it from that point of view. But since `long` and `double` both use 64 bits, there is an isomorphism that preserves comparison. I guess this isomorphism isn't built in to `Double` or `Float` but it shouldn't be a more complex problem than converting a `BigDecimal` to a `long`. So, this explains why the support for `double`s isn't built-in, but it shows that it is possible. And that should be enough to be supported, IMO.

Answer (score 24):

Use the `@DecimalMin` annotation.
You will need to pass a literal String value, because the attrubute `value` must be constant (String.valueOf(- Math.PI)) doesn't work.
It works to validate Double attributes.

```
@DecimalMin(value = "0.01", message = "Your message...")
private Double longitude;
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks!

Comment: The javadoc of the mentioned annotation explicitly says double is not supported: "Note that double and float are not supported due to rounding errors (some providers might provide some approximative support)." so i would spend patient using this.

Comment: i guess this works (despite what the javadoc says) because the string value passed (in the annotation) is simply an argument to the BigDecimal constructor.
see: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/7b3236402fdcd0c4a713535f37b61f14d42e1553/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/bv/number/bound/decimal/AbstractDecimalMinValidator.java#L36

Comment: Yes @DecimalMin works nice, but i think the correct range could defined with: 
`@DecimalMax(value = "180.0")@DecimalMin(value = "-180.0")`